# LDAP OR condition - Invalid filter

Tags: c#, ldap

I have developed a small application which reads user information from Active directory.
In the beginning of the application I used the below filter

`search.Filter = "(&((&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=User)))(displayName=*" + username + "*))";`

This worked fine.

Now, I am giving the user an option to retrieve the employee details based on username OR office OR title fields.

The query I used to get the details is as follows, but not working. It throws and exception

**"search filter is invalid.**"

```
(&((&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=User)))(|((displayName=*" + username + "*)(l = *" + location + "*)(title=*" + title + "*))))";
```

Example: retieve the details of employee based on location : Hyderabad
The runtime query looks like this

`(&((&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=User)))(|((displayName=**)(l = *hyder*)(title=**)))`

**search filter is invalid.**

Comment: Leave the C# language tag and don't put it in the title!

Answer (score 1):

I think, as your intentions are not clear, what you are looking for is something more like:

(&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=User)(|(displayName=*sam*)(l=*location*)(title=*title*)))

```
Which could be visualized as:
(&
    (objectCategory=Person)
    (objectClass=User)
    (|
        (displayName=*sam*)
        (l=*location*)
        (title=*title*)
    )
)
```

Of course you would need to put in your code parameters instead of the values shown.